# Is another base-$2024$-Wieferich prime known?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

Wieferich-prime question about the current year :

I found only $4$ base-$2024$-Wieferich primes , in other words prime numbers $p$ satisfying $$2024^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p^2$$

```
gp > forprime(p=1,10^6,if(Mod(2024,p^2)^(p-1)==1,print1(p," ")))
3 5 17 2311
gp >
```

The only really interesting case is the prime $2311$ which happens to be a primorial plus $1$ , namely $11$#$+1$.

According to my calculations there is no further such prime upto $10^{11}$

> Is another such generalized Wieferich prime known ? How far have they be checked , if at all ?

Comment: They have been searched up to $2.4 \cdot 10^{12}$, see [link here](https://www.fermatquotient.com/FermatQuotienten/FermQ_Sorg.txt).

Comment: Mod 24 might help... the LHS is $$8^{p-1}$$ mod 24 RHS is x+1 where x is the multiplier on p^2

Comment: So x is 7 or 15 mod 24

Comment: According to the link in the comment above, $p $ could be $ 3, 5, 17,$ or $ 2311$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Those are the cases I found and mentioned and upto the search-limit , no further has been found although we can expect infinite many.